# Is it safe to use client-side language to communicate to the database (like node.js)?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to set up MySQL connection and queries using this nodejs library https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2
However, this method can show my database access auth info like so

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   database: 'test'
});
```

I wonder if this can guarantee safety.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you're asking.  It is not safe to put a database password in browser Javascript because that code is available to all.  It is safe to use a database password in server code (whether that is node.js or some other server technology) where the server has physical access security (random public can't access your code on the server).

Comment: FYI, if you're referring to node.js as "client-side language" that's not really an appropriate description.  node.js can be used for a wide variety of applications, but is very commonly used for server applications.  Javascript is similarly a language that can be used in a variety of ways.  In a browser, it is used as a client-technology.  In a node.js server, it is used as a server-technology.  The Javascript language itself isn't inherently client or server.  So, your term "client-side language" is confusing.

Comment: I see. Because nodejs come from Javascript so I have always considered node a client-side (I was wrong all the time then). With that said I supposed I can use nodejs for database access without the need to use Python for this then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript itself is not inherently client or server.  It originally became known when it was used in the browser in a client-side environment.  But, the language is just a language and can be used in lots of ways.

Then, node.js was developed that used the same Javascript language.  node.js can be used for a wide variety of applications, most of which are server side.  For example, if you are building a web server using node.js, it is as much a server-side environment as any other environment that one might build a server out of, whether the language is Python, Java, PHP, Ruby or C#.

So, using a database password in node.js server code is perfectly safe as long as you've secured both physical and network access to the server so that the general public can only use the public interface of your server and not have any access to the management of the server, your code, etc...

As it appears you already know, using a database password in client-side Javascript that runs in the browser is not safe because that code and all of it's networking is available to the general public to see.

Answer (score 1):

- It is not safe to put database access auth info in client side.
- node.js is not a client-side language, it just happens to also use
  js, and is mainly used in server side (... well, unless you are using
  electron).
- The `node-mysql2` library is supposed to be used in a node.js server
  application, without exposing anything auth info to client.